# react-native-video: react-native-video-controls onBack event executed and navigated to initial screen, but in initial screen function not working,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

[image]
[image]

These the screenshots for video playing and back to when click back button and initial screen flatlist touchable not working when clicking the list items , please give me a solution i can't find what i done wrong

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using is pretty much unmaintained and has lots of issues.

From the new [`react-native-video` documentation](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#controls) we can see there are other helper libraries:

> If needed, you can also add your controls or use a package like [react-native-video-controls](https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls) or [react-native-media-console](https://github.com/criszz77/react-native-media-console), see [Useful Side Project](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/docs/PROJECTS.md).

All those issues have been solved in [`react-native-media-console`](https://github.com/criszz77/react-native-media-console) and also brings new features like TypeScript, rewind buttons, etc.